# How to access one class from two windows (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got two `windows(MainWindow,SecondWindow)`, one `class (ExampleClass)` in `ExampleClass` two `strings (Name,SecondName)` and method with `messagebox` which should contains text from `Name + SecondName` variables.

So i want to add some text from `MainWindow` to `ExampleClass Name` string and then some text from opened `SecondWindow` to `ExampleClass SecondName` string. After that i want to click on `MainWindow` button and that should give me `messagebox` with both of strings

```
Name + SecondName
```

MainWindow :

```
  ExampleClass SomeClass = new ExampleClass();
  SomeClass.Name = MainWindowTxtBox.Text;
```

Second Window :

```
ExampleClass SomeClass = new ExampleClass();
SomeClass.SecondName = SecondWindowTxtBox.Text;
```

This will create new istance of class only for one window, is it possible to create istance for both Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`static`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static) like this:

```
class ExampleClass
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
    public static string SecondName { get; set; }

    public static void print()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Name + SecondName);
    }
}
```

Then in `MainWindow`:

```
ExampleClass.Name = MainWindowTxtBox.Text;
```

And in the `SecondWindow`:

```
ExampleClass.SecondName = SecondWindowTxtBox.Text;
```

And finally:

```
ExampleClass.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. But one class needs to know the other class. Try it like this:

```
Class1
{
  public ExampleInstance Instance { get; set; }
  //Create your Class2 object here with Class2 SecondClassObject = new Class2(this)
}

Class2
{
  private Class1 MyCreator;
  public Class2(Class1 Creator)
  {
    this.MyCreator = Creator;
  }
  //Now you can use the object with: MyCreator.Instance
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks too, tryed this method and working well too... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should then create the instances of your class in the main application instead of the windows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx):

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    protected ExampleClass() {
    }

    static ExampleClass _instance;

    public static ExampleClass Instance {
        get {
            return _instance ?? (_instance = new ExampleClass());
        }
    }
}
```

and your code will look like this:

*MainWindow*

```
 ExampleClass.Instance.Name = MainWindowTxtBox.Text;
```

*Second Window*

```
 ExampleClass.Instance.SecondName = SecondWindowTxtBox.Text;
```